# Selenium and Java: While loop not working as expected

Tags: java, selenium, while-loop, selenium-chromedriver, nosuchelementexception

I have a challenge with automating a click action and I'm struggling to understand what's wrong with the logic in my solution.

My challenge is that I need to click one of a number of different radio buttons.

Each radio button has an id of "r" + a_number.

I don't know, for any given test, what the available "r" + a_number options there will be, so I wrote this while loop, which is intended to click the first available radio button:

```
int counter = 0;

while(true) {
    counter++;
    try {
        driver.findElement(By.id("r" + counter)).click();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        continue;
    }

    break;

}
```

This isn't working as intended - could someone help me understand what's wrong?

*Note: I'm a novice with Java*

**Update**

My aim is to click the first existing radio button, so the while loop increments the counter var, let's say r=1, then attempts to click a radio button with id "r1". If there is no such element with id "r1", a NoSuchElementException is thrown, in which case the current while loop iteration should stop and start the next iteration (r = 2, try to click element "r2", if does not exist, start next while loop cycle).

Suppose we get to element "r20" and this element does in fact exist, then the button should be clicked, the exception is not thrown and so the while loop continues and hits the break command, and the while loop is terminated.

The current behaviour, however, is that the exception does not get handled even when the element does not exist, the while loop terminates, but nothing has been clicked.`

Comment: Please describe the intended and actual behaviour, including how you want to handle the case of no elements matching that id.

Comment: Hello, sorry, I updated the post.

Comment: The `break` need to be after `driver.findElement`, currently it breaks the loop regardless if the click was successful or not.

Comment: @Guy Now I'm getting a different weird error: 

'InvocationTargetException' and 'getTargetException'.


I'm pretty confused by this as the methods I'm using don't throw this exception...

Comment: @WadeByronProfe You need to post a question with the code throwing the error and the complete stack trace.

Comment: Please post the HTML of the radio button along iwth some of the surrounding HTML. Is there a label or something else around that is consistent on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with the code:

1. Loop running only once- You are breaking the loop using `break` statement, after the first iteration itself.
2. No exception thrown- You are not logging the exception. You are only executing a 'continue' statement in the catch block. You do not need the statement because the loop will go to next iteration anyway (well after you remove the break statement).

You should use this code:

```java
int counter = 0;
boolean foundElement = false;
while(!foundElement) {
    counter++;
    try {
        driver.findElement(By.id("r" + counter)).click();
        foundElement = true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
       //assuming you want to log exception. Otherwise you can leave the catch block empty.
       System.out.println(e);     
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful - I've definitely learnt more about how try-catch blocks work through this question.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this:

```
int counter = 0;

while(true) {
    counter++;
    boolean elementFound = false;
    try {
        driver.findElement(By.id("r" + counter)).click();
        elementFound = true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        continue;
    }

    if (elementFound){
       break;
    }

}
```

Comment: No, I only want to check one radio button. Once a valid one has been found and checked, the while loop should terminate.

Comment: ohh Gotcha @WadeByronProfe. I am updating my answer. Please try updated one.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure and may need little more information however, I would do it little differently

```
int counter = 0;
boolean ifNotFound = true;
while(ifNotFound) {
counter++;
try {
    driver.findElement(By.id("r" + counter)).click();
    ifNotFound = false;
  } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    System.out.println("exception caught");
  }
}
```

I am just trying to click and if it is successful then will set the while loop to false and it will break.
It may be possible that the exception you are catching is not the one is being thrown so you may try to change it to generic `Exception` and if that works then you can catch more specific one or more than one if you need to.